# How to create a windows ec2 instance with domain join and preinstalled applications

Tags: amazon-web-services, automation, terraform, aws-cloudformation

I am creating windows EC2 instances in my work and joining domain, then installing 10 third party applications, it takes me almost 2 to 3hours time to make server up and running.
And I am repeating the same task for each projects.

Instead of repeating the same, would like to go with any automated way to create, join domain and install applications which are centrally located.

Creating golden image with all apps installed will not be perfect solution as my apps keep on change for different stacks,

Kindly suggest me what can be  suitable solution.

Comment: An Amazon EC2 instance is exactly the same as any other Windows computer, so use whatever tools/utilities you would use on them. You would probably get a better answer to this question at https://serverfault.com/.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein after creating the machine, its similar to normal windows server, but I wanted to do other automation during the booting time. Hope you did not get my requirement.

Comment: When an EC2 instance boots for the first time, it can run a script provided via the User Data field. This script can run in a CMD or PowerShell process. But, you are responsible for writing the script. See: [Running commands on your Windows instance at launch - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-windows-user-data.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to first launch the Instance and make them seamless domain joined to your Active directory.

Also, make sure that you make all the Instance as Managed, so that you can use AWS Systems Manager to Manage multiple Instances at once. You can tag the Instances as per the Instance role and perform action on all the Tag Instances at once, or you can simply select the Instance when using Systems Manager.

For Example, you can use Distributor to Install the necessary packages that you need for multiple Instances simultaneously.

[1] System Manager : [https://aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/#:~:text=AWS%20Systems%20Manager%20helps%20you,or%20anything%20else%20you%20choose](https://aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/#:%7E:text=AWS%20Systems%20Manager%20helps%20you,or%20anything%20else%20you%20choose).

[2] Distributor : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/distributor.html

[3] Registering Instances with Systems Manager: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DQ619NSwoGg

[4] Install or update packages : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/distributor-working-with-packages-deploy.html